# Fix code to extracts multiple values from a string, then sends all them to a function and replaces those modified values in the original string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text_to_check = "En ese sitio [(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)to(2022-09-04 04:30 am)][] vi que hay algunos campamentos y [(2022-09-06 04:00 am)to(2022-09-05 04:15 am)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 22:00 pm montanas, de alli] cerca de hasta las 23:00 pm hs"
```

I need to rearrange the datetime patterns if the time periods are reversed, for example :

**Input**: `[(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)to(2022-09-04 04:30 am)]`

Correct **output**: `[(2022-09-04 04:30 am)to(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)]`

**Input**: `[(2022-09-06 04:00 am)to(2022-09-05 04:15 am)]`

Correct **output**: `[(2022-09-05 04:15 am)to(2022-09-06 04:00 am)]`

And this is the function that contains the replacement logic, which must receive the substring with the values of `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, and `am or pm`

```py
def reorder_inconsistent_time_periods(input_text_to_check):
    print(repr(input_text_to_check))

    #Extract dates and hour values
    #-------------------
    date_in_numbers = r"\d{4}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}"
    time_in_numbers = r"(\d{2})[\s|]*(?::|)[\s|]*(\d{2})[\s|]*(?:am|pm)"
    date_and_time_re_pattern = "[(" + date_in_numbers + " " + time_in_numbers + ")to(" + date_in_numbers + " " + time_in_numbers + ")]"
    time_groups = []
    m0 = re.search(date_and_time_re_pattern, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE)
    if m0:
        time_groups = m0.groups()
        print(time_groups)
    #-------------------

    #This time 1 has to be less than time 2
    year_1, month_1, day_1, hour_1, minute_1, am_or_pm_1 = time_groups[0], time_groups[1], time_groups[2], time_groups[3], time_groups[4], time_groups[5]
    year_2, month_2, day_2, hour_2, minute_2, am_or_pm_2 = time_groups[6], time_groups[7], time_groups[8], time_groups[9], time_groups[10], time_groups[11]
    same_year, same_month, same_day, same_hour, same_minute = False, False, False, False, False
    reorder_time_period = ""

    if(int(year_2) < int(year_1)):
        #reorder times
        reorder_time_period = "[(" + year_2 + "-" + month_2 + "-" + day_2 + " " + hour_2 + ":" + minute_2 + " " + am_or_pm_2 + ")to(" + year_1 + "-" + month_1 + "-" + day_1 + " " + hour_1 + ":" + minute_1 + " " + am_or_pm_1 + ")]"
    else:
        if(int(year_2) == int(year_1)): same_year = True

        if(int(month_2) < int(month_1)):
            #reorder times
            reorder_time_period = "[(" + year_2 + "-" + month_2 + "-" + day_2 + " " + hour_2 + ":" + minute_2 + " " + am_or_pm_2 + ")to(" + year_1 + "-" + month_1 + "-" + day_1 + " " + hour_1 + ":" + minute_1 + " " + am_or_pm_1 + ")]"
        else:
            if(int(month_2) == int(month_1)): same_month = True

            if(int(day_2) < int(day_1)):
                #reorder times
                reorder_time_period = "[(" + year_2 + "-" + month_2 + "-" + day_2 + " " + hour_2 + ":" + minute_2 + " " + am_or_pm_2 + ")to(" + year_1 + "-" + month_1 + "-" + day_1 + " " + hour_1 + ":" + minute_1 + " " + am_or_pm_1 + ")]"
            else:
                if(int(day_2) == int(day_1)): same_day = True

                if(int(hour_2) < int(hour_1)):
                    #reorder times
                    reorder_time_period = "[(" + year_2 + "-" + month_2 + "-" + day_2 + " " + hour_2 + ":" + minute_2 + " " + am_or_pm_2 + ")to(" + year_1 + "-" + month_1 + "-" + day_1 + " " + hour_1 + ":" + minute_1 + " " + am_or_pm_1 + ")]"
                else:
                    if(int(day_2) == int(day_1)): same_hour = True

                    if(int(minute_2) < int(minute_1)):
                        #reorder times
                        reorder_time_period = "[(" + year_2 + "-" + month_2 + "-" + day_2 + " " + hour_2 + ":" + minute_2 + " " + am_or_pm_2 + ")to(" + year_1 + "-" + month_1 + "-" + day_1 + " " + hour_1 + ":" + minute_1 + " " + am_or_pm_1 + ")]"
                    else:
                        if(int(minute_2) == int(minute_1)): same_minute = True

                        if ( (same_year == True) and (same_month == True) and (same_day == True) and (same_hour == True) and (same_minute == True) ):
                            #It is not necessary to establish a period, you could only put a single date
                            reorder_time_period = "[(" + year_1 + "-" + month_1 + "-" + day_1 + " " + hour_1 + ":" + minute_1 + " " + am_or_pm_1 + ")]"
                        else:
                            #There is no need to reorder anything because the time period in the input string is well established
                            reorder_time_period = input_text_to_check

    return reorder_time_period
```

Here I establish the regex that conditions the call to the function that will be in charge of reordering the data

```py
date_in_numbers = r"\d{4}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}"
time_in_numbers = r"(\d{2})[\s|]*(?::|)[\s|]*(\d{2})[\s|]*(?:am|pm)"
date_and_time_re_pattern = "[(" + date_in_numbers + " " + time_in_numbers + ")to(" + date_in_numbers + " " + time_in_numbers + ")]"

input_text_to_check = re.sub(date_and_time_re_pattern, reorder_inconsistent_time_periods, input_text_to_check)

print(repr(input_text_to_check))
```

This should print the original string but with the time periods reordered :

```
"En ese sitio [(2022-09-04 04:30 am)to(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)][] vi que hay algunos campamentos y [(2022-09-05 04:15 am)to(2022-09-06 04:00 am)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 22:00 pm montanas, de alli] cerca de hasta las 23:00 pm hs"
```

the problem is that for some reason this error appears in the regex pattern line, although I don't understand why this is appear.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    m0 = re.search(date_and_time_re_pattern, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE)
    raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 91
```

I hope you can help me, maybe even find a more convenient way to do this.

Comment: `find a more convenient way to do this` ... parse each timestamp into a bona fide datetime and then compare them.

Comment: The other option is do the `time_groups = m0.groups()` inside the function `reorder_inconsistent_time_periods()`, And that way things would be extracted better and you would only have to pass a single value to the function, however the error that arises is the same as that specified in the question. Now I will edit the question that way so you can see it better although the error will be the same

Comment: you can avoid most of the regex and parse extracted timestamps into datetime object with `datetime.strptime("2022-09-04 15:10 pm", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p")`, then just compare the left and right datetime objects with `>`

Comment: You should not wrap the pattern with `[...]`, it makes a character class out of the pattern.

Comment: @Anentropic The problem with that... is that the reordering is basically a replacement, for which I inevitably need (in my opinion) the `re.sub()` method and the regex whose pattern detects the substring `"[(2022-09-04 15:10 pm )to(2022-09-04 04:30 am)]"` (and all others subtrings where the pattern matches) within the original string. And from there we basically enter the problem of the question, since there is an error in the regex pattern of detection and extraction of the substrings that must be evaluated and perhaps replaced (reordered).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there any way to be able to evaluate the pattern counting with the square brackets `[ ]` ?

Comment: To match  a literal `[` char, you need to escape it, `\[`. If that is what you meant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have added the escape char `/ ` in this lines `date_and_time_re_pattern = "\[(" + date_in_numbers + " " + time_in_numbers + ")to(" + date_in_numbers + " " + time_in_numbers + ")]"`  as you said, although it no longer throws the error, the regex continues to fail since it still does not detect a match

Comment: So what is the input? Please share a regex101.com regex fiddle.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The example input is in that line `input_text_to_check = "En ese sitio [(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)to(2022-09-04 04:30 am)][] vi que hay algunos campamentos y [(2022-09-06 04:00 am)to(2022-09-05 04:15 am)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 22:00 pm montanas, de alli] cerca de hasta las 23:00 pm hs"`, in this case the regex pattern should detect 2 substrings for validity and send them to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `re.sub` with a callback function.  We can match the datetime and am/pm components in 4 separate capture groups.  Then, parse each datetime string into a bona fide datetime.  Finally, compare the two datetimes to determine the correct order.  Note that your times are already in 24 hour format, so the am/pm values are superfluous and we don't need to parse them.

```py
def repl(m):
    str1 = m.group(1)
    dt1 = datetime.strptime(m.group(1), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    p1 = m.group(2)
    str2 = m.group(3)
    dt2 = datetime.strptime(m.group(3), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    p2 = m.group(4)
    if dt1 < dt2:
        output = f"[({str1} {p1})to({str2} {p2})]"
    else:
        output = f"[({str2} {p2})to({str1} {p1})]"
    return output

input_text_to_check = "En ese sitio [(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)to(2022-09-04 04:30 am)][] vi que hay algunos campamentos y [(2022-09-06 04:00 am)to(2022-09-05 04:15 am)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 22:00 pm montanas, de alli] cerca de hasta las 23:00 pm hs"
output = re.sub(r'\[\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}) (am|pm)\)to\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}) (am|pm)\)\]', repl, input_text_to_check)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> En ese sitio [(2022-09-04 04:30 am)to(2022-09-04 15:10 pm)][] vi que hay algunos campamentos y [(2022-09-05 04:15 am)to(2022-09-06 04:00 am)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 22:00 pm montanas, de alli] cerca de hasta las 23:00 pm hs